# Spring security with OAuth and Spring MVC settings from xml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security

I have a problem to properly configure Spring oauth using xml, as I have to add this support to an existing project is required to perform the configuration from XML, I have to integrate Spring MVC, Spring and Spring Security OAuth. I have a project which I have set for trial purposes Spring MVC and Spring security and I have another project where I could configure Spring Oauth it performs authentication password, I could not make it work integrating OAuth (safely through verification code) in the first project, not to me this missing, any suggestion or tip to configure this?

*File: spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 

http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd">

    <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    </security:global-method-security>


    <security:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />

        <security:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </security:http>


    <!-- This is where we tells spring security what URL should be protected  and what roles have access to them -->
    <security:http pattern="/oauth/api/**" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/api/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </security:http>



    <!-- Configuracion de spring global  -->

    <security:http pattern="/login**" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/login/**" security="none" />

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER') or #oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/main" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER') or #oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <security:form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessRedirectHandler" 
            login-page="/login" default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/login/fail" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/login" delete-cookies="true" invalidate-session="true" />
    </security:http>

    <bean id="authenticationSuccessRedirectHandler" class="mx.oauth.resourceserver.AuthenticationHandler" />

    <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="marcos" password="pwd" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>


<!-- Configuracion 2 Oauth -->
    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

    <oauth:authorization-server  client-details-service-ref="clientDetails"  token-services-ref="tokenServices" user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler" >
        <oauth:authorization-code/>
        <oauth:implicit/>
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"/>
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
        <!-- client -->
        <oauth:client client-id="restapp2" authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials" authorities="ROLE_USER" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />
        <oauth:client client-id="restapp" authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit" secret="restapp" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </oauth:client-details-service>

    <!-- This defined token store, we have used inmemory tokenstore for now  but this can be changed to a user defined one -->
    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />

    <!-- This is where we defined token based configurations, token validity 
        and other things -->
    <bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="120" />
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userApprovalHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
        <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="accessConfirmationController" class="mx.oauth.resourceserver.AccessConfirmationController">
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref=""clientDetails />
        <property name="approvalStore" ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```